# Kotlin Console Application: Base64.decode(iv, Base64.DEFAULT) gives Unresolved reference: decode

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a Kotlin AES decrypter and because of this I am using the Base64.decode function. However I cannot solve the reference error of the Base64 class. This is not an Android app, but a Kotlin Console Application that I run on my Windows machine in IntelliJ.

- Kotlin 1.6
- IDE: IntelliJ 2021.2.3
- JVM 1.6.0
- jvmTarget 1.8

**My code:**

```
import java.util.*
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec

class test {
    fun test(){
        val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(Base64.decode("iv", Base64.DEFAULT))
    }
}
```

**I've also tried:**

```
import java.util.Base64
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec

class test {
    fun test(){
        val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(Base64.decode("iv", Base64.DEFAULT))
    }
}
```

**Both gives the error:**

> Unresolved reference: decode'

and

> Unresolved reference: DEFAULT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base64.decode` belongs to `android.util` package, which you can only use in an Android application.

For using `Base64` decoder in an `intellij` kotlin project, use `Base64` decoder provided in `java.util` package.

```
Base64.getDecoder().decode("iv")
```

Comment: Thank you. And do you know what to do fo the second part "Base64.DEFAULT" ?

Comment: You don't need that part. It already works in that mode.